# Operating on Multiple Rows in Apache Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am trying to create a function in Apache Spark SQL that operates on multiple rows of data but have not been able to find a way of doing this directly in Spark - in Java.

My current solution has been to extract the data out of Spark DataFrames and into Java Lists for processing before returning back to a Spark DataFrame. This is not ideal performance-wise.

The best option seems to be [Window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html), but unfortunately these require Hive context, which I don't have access to. The [explode() function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#explode(scala.collection.Seq,%20scala.Function1,%20scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag)) seems another option, but again, this is Scala-specific and I was unable to get it working in Java.

Perhaps this could be done by converting the DataFrame back into an RDD?

If anyone has any tips or suggestions as to how this may be done for Apache Spark SQL in Java, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**: Example provided:

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
|   Item   | Timestamp | Difference |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|     A    |   11:00   |    02:00   |
|     A    |   13:00   |      -     |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|     B    |   09:00   |      -     |
+----------+-----------+------------+
|     C    |   15:15   |    00:20   |
|     C    |   15:35   |    01:30   |
|     C    |   17:05   |      -     |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

So in the example, I am trying to operate on pairs of rows, grouped by Item, to calculate the time difference between each item row.

Such a task is possible with LAG() and LEAD() functions in SQL, but these require Hive in Spark.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you'd like it to work? Do you want a function to apply over the entire rowset or just a part? My first thought is depending on the complexity it sounds like a GROUPBY with a UDF.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear - I am trying to operate over several rows and not the entire row set. I have provided an example above as requested.

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 1.5 you can now define UDAFs, or User Defined Aggregate Functions to let you perform custom aggregations over groups of input data. I think this is probably the closest thing I've seen to what you're looking for.

Generally you'll need to create a class that extends `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` and implements the required methods which involve initialization, merging, and aggregating.

Once you've created that you can just instanciate it, register it, and then use it within your SQL.

```
val myAggregation = new MyAggregation 
sqlContext.udf.register("MY_AGG", myAggregation)
```

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with UDAFs, but was under the impression they operated on all of the data rather than subsets. I suppose it could be done by creating a list of all the data and then performing the calculation of the time differences in the `evaluate()` function - but wouldn't that be effectively the same as extracting the data out of Spark into a list and processing it in Java?

Comment: @ab853 well yes, they operate on the whole dataset, but if you combine it with a `GROUP BY Item` , wouldn't it be applied to each subset? Even without the group by you could combine based on field, right? I'm very new to UDAFs but I'd assume that Spark would optimize it better than a pure list.

Comment: UserDefinedAggregateFunction was deprecated. Aggregator[IN, BUF, OUT] should now be registered as a UDF via the functions.udaf(agg) method.